# Warning on QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer

I have a QGuiApplication which uses Gstreamer to connect a webcam. I wanted to make the webcam turn off when the application is closed, so I wrote the code:

```
    QObject::connect(&app, &QGuiApplication::aboutToQuit, [&]() {
            if (pipeline) {
                gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
                gst_object_unref(pipeline);
                pipeline = nullptr;
            }
        });
```

Application works fine, but i always have warning on QObject::connect, which says:\

```
Invalid arguments
Candidates are:
QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *, const char *, const char *, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
```

Could anybody help to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Please show the full text of the error message. I don't see how your application can be working fine with a compiler error?

Comment: where do you get that warning? Formatting looks like it was copied from some display of your IDE. When it matters, dont trust anybody but your compiler. Find the output of the compiler and post it here.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai lots of Qt errors are reported at runtime, and I suspect this is a runtime message as well.

Comment: Which specific version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Create a [mcve], a single .cpp file with empty `QGuiApplicationWindow` and no gstreamer or anything, just a debug print in the lambda. Does that give the same warning? Edit the question to show that code. If it doesn't give the warning, try to see what's different.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You're right it's runtime error

Comment: @AlanBirtles it's a runtime error. In my question the full version of the warning is presented

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Everything compiles fine, there are no errors or warnings. My warning is a runtime message.

Comment: Are you sure it's a runtime error, not an intellisense error or something? We still need a [mre]